# Safe link revision

Tags: discussion

I just saw [this revision](https://askubuntu.com/posts/808587/revisions) on a post, and all the revision was take a link to a search engine query. He even missed a typo I made. What's up?

- **Any guideline about this?**

Comment: So you can see the revision. I'll use bold

Comment: People miss typos, once you get 2k, it is a lot less important to get every tiny thing because there is no review of the edit and multiple users will often work on a post overtime. In short, muru fixed what he noticed (obvious noise) and removed it, now you have fixed the typo, this is community editing in action :)

Comment: This http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/15154/what-is-considered-extra-noise seems related.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For some reason, known only to yourself, you decided to add a random link to a search query for "Happy Llamas". Since that has absolutely nothing to do with your question, isn't adding anything remotely relevant to it and doesn't help people understand it, it is just noise and was correctly removed.

We try to keep questions streamlined and to the point. One of the guidelines for posting on Stack Exchange sites is "no chit-chat". It's even one of the first things mentioned in the [tour](https://askubuntu.com/tour):

> This site is all about getting answers. It's not a discussion forum. There's no chit-chat.

So yes, please don't add such noise to your posts. Everything mentioned in a question or answer should be directly relevant to the issue at hand. Anything else should be removed. The edit was fine.

Comment: Ok TY, and what about revision quality ? This is his feedback, "deleted 94 characters in body; edited tags" Now I know is the chit chat part.

Comment: @userDepth yes, that's the default message added by the system when no reason was given by the editor. An explanation would have been better, true. I guess the editor assumed the reason was obvious since he removed something that was absolutely irrelevant to the question.

Comment: Yeah I think I'll leave that to my profile (maybe)

Comment: If you like, sure. Just please stop adding it to your posts.

Comment: @userDepth I'm cool with discussing happy llamas in [chat].

Comment: @Fiksdal XD what?

Comment: @userDepth You, know... Terdon said you had been posting about Llamas and stuff.

Comment: @Fiksdal Yes, I'm curious about the chat proposal. I just can't chat now.

Comment: @userDepth Don't worry, it was like a half-joke. I do like Llamas, though.

Comment: @Fiksdal Well you can get why I didn't get the joke XD

Comment: @userDepth Yeah.